# How can I remove on-screen keys in Eclipse built Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, java-me, key, touchscreen

I developed a view based application for Android but I get navigation keys on the touch screen, up/down/select/ok. I do not need these keys and I want to remove them so that they don't show on the screen so that the application displays full screen. Anything to do with LWUIT? Help please.
Thanks

Comment: Well, Android itself doesn't add navigation keys to apps, so if you're using LWUIT it probably has to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done inside your android emulator. Press menu on home screen, open "Settings", then "language and keyboard", and disable all keyboards. The emulator keyboard (not the on screen one, but your PC keyboard and button keyboard on the right) is considered as hardware keyboard, and will still work.

Comment: thanks :) that is helpful but the thing is that I uploaded the app on a real device. I'm using lwuit, I guess that's the part I should be working on but the problem is that I cant seem to find a way around it.